# jQuery .prepend to non-existent element - is it a JS bug?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, prepend

I want to prepend a form to an element on a page right after the parent element is added to DOM. When I prepend too early, i.e. the parent element doesn not exist yet I get a strange beheavor.

```
jQuery(".myDiv").prepend('<div id="myForm">Content</div>');
```

If I check the existance of the prepent element right after with jQuery or even with JS like this:

```
var res = document.getElementById("myForm")
console.log(res);
```

I get the prepend element in console. But if the parent element didn't exist yet then no prepend element appears on the page and if I check the same element one second later:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    var res = document.getElementById("myForm")
    console.log(res);
}, 1000);
```

then I get *null*

After looping through this when the parent element finnaly gets added to the page my prepend element does not disappear.

So it looks like whatever I prepend gets added to the DOM first but then get's rejected by DOM after it is found that the parent element does not exist. But is this a normal beheavor?

Comment: I can't seem to reproduce what you're describing. [See this JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wchs6qen/) for more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's working great.

```js
// When div is present
jQuery(".myDiv").prepend('<div id="myForm">Content</div>');

var res = document.getElementById("myForm")
console.log('mydiv:',res);

setTimeout(function() {
    var res = document.getElementById("myForm")
    console.log('mydiv:',res);
}, 1000);

// When div is not present
jQuery(".noDiv").prepend('<div id="noForm">Content</div>');

var res = document.getElementById("noForm")
console.log('noForm:',res);

setTimeout(function() {
    var res = document.getElementById("noForm")
    console.log('noForm:',res);
}, 1000);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="myDiv"></div>
```

I think you are removing the item after the item is added. It's an assumption

Comment: What the OP is saying is that if there isn't any `.myDiv` on the page, `document.getElementById("myForm")` doesn't return `null` if it is called immediately after `...prepend(...)`

Comment: No its giving null to me

Comment: Ok, the parent div is added by a third party script so I'm not sure what that does, it is pretty much can be that parent div gets added and then removed and then added again. So what Aman says can pretty much be the correct thing